# Reduce bitrate of video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, bitrate

I'm using ffmpeg to check the bitrate of given videos and my goal is to reduce it to half of the original bitrate.

For test purpose I executed this command

```
ffmpeg -i example.avi
```

and I saw that the bitrate of the videos was around 1030 kb/s

I want to know which is the unit that ffmpeg uses for bitrate.

```
ffmpeg -i example.aviffmpeg -b 515 new_video.avi
```

I used b:a and b:v for audio and video, but the result is not correct again
I tried with just 515 and 515k, but still not correct ...

My goal is to have output video with 515 kb/s bitrate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i example.avi -b:v 515k new_video.avi
```

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description

If that's not what you need, let me refer to the accepted answer here: [FFMPEG ignores bitrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604534/ffmpeg-ignores-bitrate?rq=1)

> [...] You may also want to specify a bitrate for the audio, e.g. -b:a 32k
> (or -ba 32k). If you want the total bitrate to be 128kbps, specify
> audio and video bitrates that add up to a total of 128k [...]

Comment: Thank you very much! The both links has some usefull information