# ffmpeg enforces bitrate value other than what specified

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate, bitrate

I have a folder containing 1701 image frames named "frame0000.jpg", "frame0001.jpg",..., "frame1700.jpg". When I try to convert them to a video using this command:

```
ffmpeg -r:1751/61 -b:2400k -i frame%3d.jpg video1.avi
```

It produces a video with a bitrate of 717kbs and 25 frames/second (so the FPS is also different than what I specified!); hence, it has a poor quality.

I read a lot about this issue such as:
[FFMPEG ignores bitrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604534/ffmpeg-ignores-bitrate)

But couldn't find the solution to my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Bitrate for output goes after the input e.g. `ffmpeg -framerate 1751/61 -i frame%3d.jpg -b:v 2400k video1.avi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixed command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1751/61 -i frame%3d.jpg -b:v 2400k video1.avi
```

---

### Option placement is important

[Syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) is:

```
  ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

### Use valid options

- `-r:1751/61` is incorrect. Use `-framerate 1751/61`. The [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) prefers `-framerate`, not `-r`.
- `-b:2400k` is incorrect. Use `-b:v 2400k`

### Refer to the log

It should have provided errors to help you determine the problem:

- `Invalid stream specifier: 1751/61`
- `Option b (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) cannot be applied to input -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.`